# Recursive chown starting with the directory above current directory

Tags: command-line, chown

I couldn't log in to my "admin" account and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> showed all my files were owned by my "standard" user.  Odd.

So I carefully changed to `/home/admin` and did a

```
sudo chown -R admin:admin *
```

(and `.*` too).

Great.

Then I couldn't log in as my "standard" user and it turns out that all the files in `/home/standard` were now owned by "admin".

Pretty humorous. Why is this happening?

```
sudo chown -R standard:standard /home/standard/*
```

did the same thing, changed `/home/admin` as well as `/home/standard`.

I'm more confused than usual because I tried to upgrade to 15.04 and that pretty much wrecked my computer so I'm putting things back with 14.04, please be patient with me.

Comment: Perhaps one is a symbolic link to the other? what does `ls -l /home` say?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This issue is caused because you have run:

```
sudo chown -R admin:admin .*
```

We know that `.` indicates the current directory and `..` indicates the parent directory. When you run the command with `.*`, it simply means that match any hidden file in the current directory (stating with `.`), the current directory itself (`.`), the parent directory (`..`). Simply put anything after `.` (`*` means 0 or more characters). As a result the parent directory along with all of it child directories get `chown`-ed to `admin:admin`.

Look at this test:

```bsh
test$ ls -al
drwxrwxr-x 4 foo foo 4096 Jun  3 07:15 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 foo foo 4096 Jun  2 18:06 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Jun  3 07:15 egg
drwxrwxr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Jun  3 07:12 spam

$ sudo chown -R bar:bar spam/.*

test$ ls -al
drwxrwxr-x 4 bar  bar  4096 Jun  3 07:15 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 foo  foo  4096 Jun  2 18:06 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 bar  bar  4096 Jun  3 07:15 egg
drwxrwxr-x 2 bar  bar  4096 Jun  3 07:12 spam
```

To revert back you need to `chown` the affected directories again.

I am not really sure what your plan was, but here are some ideas:

- To `chown` any directory recursively (including hidden files):

  ```
  sudo chown -R foo:foo /spam/egg/
  ```
- To `chown` only the files (including hidden files) inside that directory (not the directory itself):

  ```
  (shopt -s dotglob && sudo chown -R foo:foo egg/*)
  ```
- To `chown` only the non-hidden files (without the directory itself):

  ```
  sudo chown -R foo:foo egg/*
  ```

Comment: Thank you, I get it now...  duh ;P  Still don't know why the owner changed in the first place unless it was somehow related to Grub giving me an error and crashing the 14.04 install program on me.  My standard user was the the first one I created and I later demoted that one and created a new one.

Comment: @DavidP I am not clear what you are getting at..

Answer (score 3):

I think it's the ".*" parameter for files; that matches everything starting with ".", including the "." **and** the ".." files.  The ".." is the parent directory, which includes everything under it.

The best way is to back up one folder, and specify the actual folder you want to change (/home/admin).